# how to debug mysql join error

Tags: mysql, database, join

I get below error when I execute SQL statement mentioned under code. How to debug this issue?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UNION select from employee right outer join
>   department where employee.dept_no <>' at line 1

code

```
select * 
from employee 
full outer JOIN department 
on employee.dept_no is null or department.dept_no is null; 

select * 
from employee 
left outer join department 
UNION 
select from employee 
right outer join department 
where employee.dept_no <> department.dept_no;
```

Comment: The syntax error is simple, but your query looks suspect.  What exactly are you trying to achieve? Show the table definitions, some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You missed column names(`*`) in the second select in UNION.

It was `UNION select  from employee` changed to => `UNION select *  from employee`.

And as @Drew said missed `ON` clause with `OUTER JOINS`.

This query will work fine.

```
select * 
from employee
 left outer join  department  ON --Some condition here--
 UNION
 select * 
from employee
 right outer join department ON --Some condition here--
WHERE employee.dept_no <> department.dept_no;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah .. Myself missed a `ON` clause.. Right?

Comment: you got it. And without a schema, we are out of luck